# как поместить в swift 3 проект .a .h файлы и работать с ними

Tags: objective-c, swift3

есть два файла libPrinterSDK.a и PrinterSDK.h
я создал bridging header все сделал как описано в документации apple и когда я пытаюсь импортировать PrinterSDK в контроллер он мне выдает ошибку что такого модуля нет в помине

Comment: вот import
http://prntscr.com/fpro5w
bridgind header
http://prntscr.com/fprogi
вот картинки

Comment: can you share the libPrinterSDK.a file; my file stop working after 4 days of deployment on iOS... thanks

Answer (score 0):

добавьте в bridging header

```
#import "PrinterSDK.h"
```

теперь вы можете просто использовать ваш класс PrinterSDK в swift коде как любой другой класс, для примера

```
let printer = PrinterSDK()
```

Если не работает то проверьте в настройках проекта подключен ли bridging header [пример](http://www.learnswiftonline.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/swift_bridging_header_2.png)

Comment: Простите нет не подходит это есть