# Как в iOS можно реализовать ViewPager на полэкрана?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, android-viewpager

Как я могу сделать в iOS такую же вещь, как на картинке. Ну или хотя бы что-то похожее, чтоб не ViewControllers листать, а какие-то Views в центре экрана.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: скролл вью с pagination

Answer (score 0):

Есть либа на objective-c [ссылка](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel) с ее помощью можно очень просто сделать то что вы хотите,[тут](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/icarousel) можно поклацать пример проекта. Вам нужен Linear или Rotary type. Подключить в swift проект можно используя bridging header файл [вопрос по установке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/685431/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2-swift-3-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82-a-h-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D1%8B-%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81-%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8/685537#685537). Установить можно через [cocoapods](https://cocoapods.org/pods/iCarousel) или выкачав папку iCarousel с github.

Пример того что вам нужно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

использовать CollectionView (не CollectionViewController) на половину View
 или использовать библиотеки например https://github.com/superpeteblaze/ScalingCarousel
https://github.com/DroidsOnRoids/SwiftCarousel
https://github.com/BenEmdon/CenteredCollectionView